# Create a uneven union query with uneven number of fields

Tags: ms-access-2010

Is there a way in access to create a union query with uneven number of fields.  The first half of the union query would only have 5 fields and the second part would have 7 fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can have imaginary fields:

```
 SELECT RealField1, RealField2, RealField3, RealField4 FROM Table
 UNION ALL
 SELECT Null As RealField1, Null As RealField2, RealField3, RealField4 FROM Table
```

Comment: so you do you need to create these junk fields in the table or can you just place them in the query